# recording voice in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to build app like talking tom cat. I am able to record the voice and play the voice in chipmunk style. but it records background noise also. It does not record only human voice records everything. I want to record only human voice. Could anyone help on this.

Comment: you should try to use an audio filter on your recorded audio. :)

Comment: yes I tried but unable to get. Do you have any link for it?